# sortable columns on a custom post type won't work

Tags: custom-post-types

I have picked through Scribu's post very carefully and cannot determine where the issue is.

Here is the code:

```
// Register the column
function event_date_column_register( $columns ) {
$columns['event-date'] = __( 'Event Date', 'my-plugin' );

return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-event_columns', 'event_date_column_register' );

// Display the column content
function event_date_column_display( $column_name, $post_id ) {
if ( 'event-date' != $column_name )
    return;

$event_date = get_post_meta($post_id, 'event-date', true);
if ( !$event_date )
    $event_date = '<em>' . __( 'undefined', 'my-plugin' ) . '</em>';

echo $event_date;
}
add_action( 'manage_event_custom_column', 'event_date_column_display', 10, 2 );

// Register the column as sortable
function event_date_column_register_sortable( $columns ) {
$columns['event-date'] = 'event-date';

return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-event_sortable_columns', 'event_date_column_register_sortable' );


function event_date_column_orderby( $vars ) {
if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'event-date' == $vars['orderby'] ) {
    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
        'meta_key' => 'event-date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order'     => 'asc'
    ) );
}

return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'event_date_column_orderby' );
```

I have a custom post type for Event with a custom field: event-date  dates are entered: 2011/06/21

Is this something stupid I have missed or this won't do what I want?  It does put the heading up at the top of the admin events list but nothing shows in each line item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe the right hook for displaying the actual column content (each line) is

```
manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column
```

so change in your code:

```
add_action( 'manage_event_custom_column', 'event_date_column_display', 10, 2 );
```

to:

```
add_action( 'manage_event_posts_custom_column', 'event_date_column_display', 10, 2 );
```